# Keep getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, body-parser, es6-modules

I cant pass this functions(**first code**) to my players.js(**Second code**) file as I keep getting **SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'** I have got around this problem by using **module.exports =** but this solution doesn't seem to work with **module.exports = ReadPlayers, ReadPlayer, CreatePlayer, DeletePlayer**

I only copy over one of the functions to make it easy to look at

```
function CreatePlayer(req, res) {
    let PlayerDoc = new Players(req.body);
    PlayerDoc.save()
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('Player saved');
            res.location(result.uri)
                .status(201)
                .json({ id: result._id, uri: `/Players/${result.id}` })
        })

    .catch((error) => {
        res.status(412).json({ status: 'fail', message: 'not created' })
    })
    console.log('proising to save');
}


export default { ReadPlayers, ReadPlayer, CreatePlayer, DeletePlayer }
```

```
const express = require("express");

const { db } = require('../models/PlayerService');

const router = express.Router();


router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    db.CreatePlayer(req, res);
})

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    db.ReadPlayers(req, res);
})

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    db.ReadPlayer(req, res);
})

router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    db.DeletePlayer(req, res);
})

module.exports = router;
//export default router;
```

Comment: `module.exports = { ReadPlayers, ReadPlayer, CreatePlayer, DeletePlayer }`

Comment: Works now thanks. @Mr.Alien

Comment: You have to choose between old-style `require()` import/export and new-style ES2015 import export; they're different. For the new style stuff you have to explicitly tell Node that a source file is a new-style module.